# Import RSA public key saved with pycrypto 2.0.1 into newer versions

Tags: python, pycrypto

I have a pickled RSA public key generated using PyCrypto 2.0.1.  I'm looking to upgrade my application to use PyCrypto 2.5.

The pickle key data begins with
iCrypto.PublicKey.RSA\nRSAobj_c

Unfortunately, RSAobj_c is removed in PyCrypto >=2.1, so depickling fails.

How should I go about making the key compatible with the new PyCrypto?

Comment: Why not exporting the key using a standard format, like PEM, in the old PyCrypto, and importing it in the new PyCrypto? Suppose `pk` is the public key in a session in which you use the old PyCrypto. You can do `pk.exportKey("PEM")` to generate a string representing the key in PEM format, which you can save to a file. After that, you open a new Python session with the new PyCrypto, you load the file you have just created and you store its content on a variable like `pkstring`. Finally, you can load the key by executing something like `pk = RSA.importKey(pkstring)`. Does this solve your problem?